# How set up editing in iOS application like contacts app

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

My designer is giving me something that looks similar to the iPad contacts app. This doesn't seem to be standard, though. I would have thought I would have found more info on this but my searches haven't brought up much, so I apologize if I've missed it. Basically we want to have a green "+" button to add an item, expanding the cell to enter data for that item when tapped (see "add new address" cell in 1st attached image below), then in 2nd image that cell expanded with address fields.

The final question relates to what seems like standard table editing behavior, but I'm not sure how to fit into this context. For the delete icon, getting it to rotate when tapped and the "delete" button to show up in the cell. As I asked earlier, how do I get the delete icon to show up to the side of the cell rather than within it and how do I get it to show up for just certain cells and not all of them? See final screenshot below.

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you look at https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/ManageInsertDeleteRow/ManageInsertDeleteRow.html

Comment: I had not seen this but it looks great. Checking it out now. Thanks!

Comment: So then looking at my 2nd screen shot, for home address, is that a single cell with 5 text fields for the data, 1 label for "home" and a vertical 1 pixel view for the label/text fields sections divider? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds complicated. Why not leverage Apple's [ABPersonViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AddressBookUI/Reference/ABPersonViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007076) to display and edit an Address Book contact?

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't associated with contacts, it's just a pattern we want to follow for something similar.